# Scala 3 IntelliJ error: ';' expected but ':' found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-3

I have a scala worksheet with the following code:

```
case class Square(width: Double):
  val area = width * width

val window = Square(2)
window.area
```

I am trying to code in IntelliJ Idea, but I am getting the following error:

> ';' expected but ':' found. case class Square(width: Double):

The code is written in Scala 3, and the IntelliSense is set up correctly and reports no error, but I have a suspicion that the compiler is using some older version of the language. Is this a compiler setup issue and how do I fix it?

Edit: I am following a Scala learning course and downloading my project from there:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/effective-scala/supplement/UShnH/scala-3-repl-and-worksheets

Comment: Such exception may occur when you have this typed as one line. ``case class Square(width: Double): val area = width * width`` Silly but try reloading file or make some changes to save it again/

Comment: are you sure you have Scala 3 installed and setup as the scala version of the project ?

Comment: @Kaa I have it on two lines. Putting it on a single line generates an Intellisense error that newline is expected. Editing and saving the file does not help.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip I am sure I have Scala 3 installed. I think I have Scala 3 as the project version but I am not sure, where are these configurations. The only SDK I can see under File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> Global Libraries is scala-sdk-2.13.8 with Scala version 3.1 (tried 3.0 too). The issue is that I do not know where else to look for the Scala version configuration.

Comment: If you don't have the Scala 3 SDK then that is the issue. First one to check is not `Platform Settings` but `Project Settings`:  File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Libraries ->  the jar version and Scala version should match. The second check is in your sbt `build.sbt`: you should find there the scala version used for your current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file was part of the project from the course I mentioned in the question. There was a file build.properties containing a single line:

```
sbt.version=1.5.3
```

After changing the version to

```
sbt.version=1.7.1
```

and relaunching Idea, the worksheet was evaluated correctly with no errors. The project was also set up to use version Java 18, which is used by sbt 1.7.1, but sbt 1.5.3 uses Java 11 instead, which might have been the issue.

Answer (score -7):

```
case class Square(width; Double);
```

Comment: I would like to suggest that you also add some commentary around your code. This will help the asker to understand the code-changes that you've suggested.